# How to sum cumulatively across columns

Tags: r, subset, dplyr

I'm new to R, and would like to modify a dataset so that each column contains the cumulative sum of the values in all the columns to its left (including itself). I'm aware of how to use `rowSums` to calculate the cumulative sum for each column separately:

```
df <- data.frame(
  jan = rep(1:2, each = 3),
  feb = rep(1:3, each = 2),
  mar = rep(5:4, each = 3),
  apr = rep(1:3, each = 2)
)
df

df %>%
  mutate(feb = rowSums(subset(., select = (jan:feb))),
         mar = rowSums(subset(., select = (jan:mar))),
         apr = rowSums(subset(., select = (jan:apr))))
```

Which produces the output I'm looking for:

```
  jan feb mar apr
1   1   2   7   8
2   1   2   7   8
3   1   3   8  10
4   2   4   8  10
5   2   5   9  12
6   2   5   9  12
```

How can I generalise this to any number of columns? I have been trying statements like this:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(-jan), ~rowSums(subset(., select = (jan:.))))
```

But I am not using `subset` correctly. Thanks in advance if you are able to help at all.

Comment: Do you need to use `mutate`? Would just running `apply` over the columns with `rowSums` of the columns with lower column indices not give you what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a litle late in the game, but if you want to keep within the tidyverse syntax, you can use a combination of pivoting to a longer format, sum by group, and then reconstitute the wider format:

```
df %>% 
  rowid_to_column("ID") %>%  #Create a ID column
  pivot_longer(cols = - ID) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% #Inteify rows as groups
  mutate(CumSum = cumsum(value)) %>% #Do the cumsum by groups
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = name, values_from = CumSum) #Reconstruct the wider format
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear what you are asking, you should provide an example output. Does this help?

```
> cumsum(colSums(df))
jan feb mar apr 
  9  21  48  60
```

or maybe this?

```
new_df <- df

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    new_df[i,] <- cumsum(unlist(df[i,]))
}

> new_df
  jan feb mar apr
1   1   2   7   8
2   1   2   7   8
3   1   3   8  10
4   2   4   8  10
5   2   5   9  12
6   2   5   9  12
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks very much.

Comment: This takes twice as long to run as the sapply version, but if it is not inside a loop or the dataframe is not large, then that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I understood that the columns should be cumulatively summed. Like this:

```
cum.df = sapply(1:ncol(df), function(col){
    rowSums(df[1:col])
})
```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    7    8
[2,]    1    2    7    8
[3,]    1    3    8   10
[4,]    2    4    8   10
[5,]    2    5    9   12
[6,]    2    5    9   12
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative with `Reduce`:

```
do.call(cbind,Reduce(`+`,lapply(df,`[`,),accumulate = TRUE))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    7    8
[2,]    1    2    7    8
[3,]    1    3    8   10
[4,]    2    4    8   10
[5,]    2    5    9   12
[6,]    2    5    9   12
```

Answer (score 1):

`apply`ing `cumsum`.

```
t(apply(df, 1, cumsum))
#      jan feb mar apr
# [1,]   1   2   7   8
# [2,]   1   2   7   8
# [3,]   1   3   8  10
# [4,]   2   4   8  10
# [5,]   2   5   9  12
# [6,]   2   5   9  12
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `rowCumsums` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
rowCumsums(as.matrix(df))
```